# Angular2 npm test throws reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, karma-runner

I created a simple component to display DoubleClick ads with Angular 2.

I'm trying to publish it to npm, and to do so I would like to test it with karma before. I can confirm it is working properly on 2 different projects, but when running `npm test` (`tsc && karma`) it throws an error:
`uncaught exception: reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators`

I found on stackoverflow that this could fix the error:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';
```

But I tried importing them in most of my files without success...

Here is [a link to my repo](https://github.com/alaborderie/ng2-ad-dfp) if someone could help me out that would be great ;) !

Thanks

Comment: Some help please ?

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround to this issue?

Comment: I imported every spec.ts file in a single test.spec.ts and run the tests from this file. At the beginning of the file i also import every shim i needed. In tsconfig be sure to output to es5. I don't test components anymore so can't help you much more